# Recovery of PSF used for deconvolution (deblurring)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two images. I know that one is the deblurred version of the other, with Wiener deconvolution.

I have no idea about the parameters used for the deconvolution.

How can I recover the point spread function used for the deconvolution?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution - Are you interested in recovering `H` or `G` or something else?

Comment: I am trying to recover G, or g.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `fft2` to both input and output, divide them to obtain estimate of transfer function, and transform that back through `ifft2`?

Comment: I tried that, but the result (ifft2 of the transfer function obtained using the method you suggested) is just noise. There is a noise parameter in the Wiener deconvolution that I need to incorporate into the recovery process somehow.